# How to make parallel piezoelectric/PVDF transducers for force measurement?

Tags: sensor, charge, piezo, piezoelectric-effect

I am having difficulty in understanding a concept since I am not in the electrical field. I am working on a project to measure the dynamic force on a surface using embedded PVDF transducers. Based on the theories I studied so far, if I connect this PVDF to the charge amplifier, the output voltage is only dependent on the feedback capacitor of the charge amplifier as follows:

[image]

Where 1/cf is the charge amplifier gain that I put it on 0.1 mV/pC and d33 is piezoelectruc charge constant around 20 pC/N. I want to measure the dynamic force F through the measured voltage signal in the experiment. The problem is that I have two pieces of PVDF to measure the force and I have to connect them together (series or parallel I don't know) to measure the voltage and force from one channel. The experiment is like below where two pieces of PVDF are bonded between two metallic material.

[image]

How can I connect these PVDF materials to measure the force through one channel? I tested the signal from each one and the voltage signal was -0.3 to 0.3 V. Both PVDF separately gave me same signal but with a phase shift because the load passes through the top surface in horizontal direction.

If I put these PVDF in parallel (all positives together / negatives together,) the voltage drops to 0.1 V. I didn't expect this and I thought I should see around 0.6 V. Then I put them in series and voltage became about 1-1.2 V but the appearance of the signal was not something I expected. I expect to see a sinusoidal voltage signal but that one was a noise signal with sudden jumps in its amplitude.

I would like to understand if I am doing something wrong here, or if generally this approach is possible, or I have to measure force from one PVDF and them multiply it by two.

Should I use the maxum amplitude to put in equation or peak to peak? I mean for each PVDF is my V value in equation 0.3 V or 0.6 V?

[PVDF datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FFDT_Series%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_FDT_Series_A1.pdf%7FCAT-PFS0008)

Comment: Please link to a data sheet for the PVDF

Comment: @RussellH Thanks for your comment. Here is the datasheet. Mine is FLDT1-028K

https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FFDT_Series%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_FDT_Series_A1.pdf%7FCAT-PFS0008